# Is closing http.server.HTTPServer guaranteed to be thread-safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-multithreading, simplehttpserver

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import threading

with HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) as httpd:
    threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever, daemon=True).start()
    # Do something ...
```

When the program exits the `with` block, is it guaranteed that `httpd` is closed properly? For example, if `httpd` is transmitting data when the code reaches the end of the `with` block, would that connection be properly cut off (or being waited for until it finishes)?

My understanding is that `ThreadingHTTPServer` should be handling these properly, because the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ThreadingMixIn) says:

> `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn.server_close()` waits until all non-daemon threads complete, except if `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn.block_on_close` attribute is false. Use daemonic threads by setting `ThreadingMixIn.daemon_threads` to True to not wait until threads complete.

But I would like to see whether Python's most basic built-in http server `HTTPServer` would also handle this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.server.HTTPServer` is a subclass of `socketserver.TCPServer` is a subclass of `socketserver.BaseServer`. In `BaseServer` `.serve_forever` is defined. Here it is made appearnt that the correct way to shutdown `.serve_forever` in a different thread is to call [`.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.shutdown). This is what you should be doing before the `with` statement ends.

Now to the question you ask: What would `serve_forever` do when you don't call `.shutdown()`? Well, I am not sure. The `__exit__` function only closes the socket, it doesn't do any cleanup. The answer appears to be 'Whatever your OSes implementation of `select.select` does when it has no sockets to select over.' What this is? Apparently, on Unix just continue like nothing happened, on Windows raise an exception? This would means on Unix the server would just continue to serve forever, while on Windows it will raise an exception. (Note that I am not sure about this. Just `.shutdown()`)

Comment: That should have answered my question. Thanks!